# AngularJs JvectorMap scalecolor

Tags: angularjs, jvectormap

I'm trying to update the series of an JvectorMap with angularJs. The problem is that the color series is modified, but it is not rendered...

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ib3Rgz?p=preview

```
           scope.$watch("datamap" , function(n,o){ 
         console.log(chart)
         if(!chart){
            $(element).width('auto')
            $(element).height(400)
            chart = $(element).vectorMap({
                    series: {
                        regions: [{
                            values: scope.mapData,
                            scale: ['#dcdcef','ceadec'],
                            normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                        }]
                    }
            })

         }else{
            console.log(chart.vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').series.regions)
            chart.vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').series.regions[0].setNormalizeFunction('polynomial')
            chart.vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').series.regions[0].setScale(['#CCCCCC','D0D0D0'])
            chart.vectorMap('get', 'mapObject').series.regions[0].setValues(scope.datamap)
         }
      });
```